# How can I hide the shadow of an object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I just want to hide the shadow of one object. How can I do it ?

[image]

Comment: If you are in Cycles, select the object, go in the Properties panel > Object > Cycles Settings, and disable Shadow

Comment: If you are in Eevee, select the object, go in the Properties panel > Material > Settings, and set 'Shadow mode' to 'None'. ; )

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't find button for disable it :/ Could you add screenshot please ? Thanks.

Comment: Found it thx again :)

Comment: @moonboots you should add an answer to help reduce unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in *Cycles Render*, select the object, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Cycles Settings*, and disable *Shadow*.

As aded by Lemon, if you are in Eevee, select the object, go in the *Properties* panel > *Material* > *Settings*, and set *Shadow mode* to *None*